# missing modules after converting .py to .exe with pyinstaller

Tags: python, module, exe, pyinstaller

I am using `pyinstaller` to convert `.py` to `.exe` however after converting, when I then run the `.exe`, a command line window pops up for a split second and closes. the  .exe isn't working almost at all, I then navigate to the `warn.txt` file and it says that there are a bunch of missing modules:

```
missing module named resource
missing module named posix
missing module named _posixsubprocess
missing module named cv2
```

and allot more (*24 in total*)

I've researched this problem and could not get a good answer iv tried converting with `--onefile` and `--onedir` and the same thing happens.

how do I import or fix these missing modules so that the **`.exe`** will run correctly or even at all?

Answer (score 1):

Try to make a spec file and use hidden_imports for the modules you are missing:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)

block_cipher = None
a = Analysis(['src\\main.py'],
         pathex=['your_path_text'],
         binaries=[],
         datas=[],
         hiddenimports=['cv2','your_missing_modules...],
         hookspath=[],
         runtime_hooks=[],
         excludes=[],
         win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
         win_private_assemblies=False,
         cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='main',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='main')
```

Then run `pyinstaller main.spec`.

Comment: so just to be clear, i need to make a .spec file with the exact content you provided and then run pyinstaller on the .spec file? not the .py file

Comment: If you run pyinstaller, it autogenerates a spec file. Just open the autogenerated one and write the missing modules in hidden imports. then run pyinstaller on the spec file. For detailed explanation see: https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html

Comment: OK so i did that and it kind of worked, so now when i run the .exe file the command line comes up for a longer period of time like the code is being run however then for a split second text shows up in the command line and then closes i was able to get a screenshot at the right time and it was because of a ```ModuleNotFoundError No module named cv2``` this was in line 1 were im importing cv2 , dose this mean that i need to install all these import modules like ```cv2 ,configparser, time``` into the install directory of the .exe?

Comment: Did you sepcify cv2 in hidden imports? Can you post the errorstack? If you run the .exe via command line it doesn't close and you have time to make a screenshot.

Comment: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "face detect.py", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
[11448] Failed to execute script test```

and yes i did add cv2 to the hiddenimports.

Comment: Do you have a cv2 folder in `dist/main`?

Comment: no it dosent seem like it , will that file be a ```.pyd``` file because there are a few ```.pyd```files here like the ```_tkinter.pyd``` witch was one thing that i imported...?

Comment: Should be a folder with a .pyd file in it. Last idea I have, would be to add your python path to the pathex in your main.spec. I.e. `pathex=['C:\dev\WinPython-64bit-3.6.3.0Qt5\python-3.6.3.amd64']`

Comment: however adding the python path to the spec file would mean that the program will not be able to run on another computer or a pc without python

Comment: oh no hold on there is a ```cv2.cp36-win_amd64.pyd``` file and a ```cv2.cp37-win32.pyd``` file ...?

Comment: "however adding the python path to the spec file would mean that the program will not be able to run on another computer or a pc without python" - No this just helps pyinstaller to find the packages. "oh no hold on there is a `cv2.cp36-win_amd64.pyd` file" and you still get cv2 not found error?

Comment: yes i still get the cv2 not found , so i add python path to the pathex and when i ran ```pyinstaller``` it gave me a ```SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape```

Comment: I forgot to copy the r before `pathex=[r'C:\dev\WinPython-64bit-3.6.3.0Qt5\python-3.6.3.amd64']`. If that doesn't work try to replace \ with \\.

Comment: ok well the ``` SyntaxError:``` went away but the ```ModuleNotFoundError``` is the same. :\

Comment: Hmm I'm pretty much out of ideas by now. Can you post a screenshot of your dist folder?

Comment: sorry , i cant seem to post a picture to stack overflow , i guess nothing relay works properly for me :)